# Release production failed: timed out waiting for the condition (No files to upload)

Tags: node.js, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

Trying to deploy a nodejs web application to AWS via CI/CD process for the first time. Project is under a Group account with other projects which have been deployed successfully so Kubernetes have been set up for the group. But we are getting the following error.

[image]

We have no clue what this means. We are using AutoDevOps.

This is how our Docker file looks like:

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

& this is how the package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "packageapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Package API",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Random Anon",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.23.3",
    "mocha": "^8.1.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

What are we doing wrong? Cannot reference other projects in the group because they are deployed using java spring boot and asp net.

Comment: Make sure  your node app running on port 5000

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit scripts in package.json and add

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy_prod": "mocha",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
```